# Match exact number of Digits and Words using Regex - Python27

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this string.

```
P O BOX 32370, CA 92263
```

And this Regex `\w{2} \d{5}`

But it matches both texts in bold. "P O B**OX 32370**, **CA 92263**"

Actually I want to extract State, and Zip code.

I want to grab **text starting and a space, then exact 2 alphabets, then one space, then exact 5 digits.**

Comment: You seem to be after a word boundary, use `\b\w{2} \d{5}\b`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add word boundary `\b` to make sure the pattern doesn't have leading or trailing word characters (alphanumeric and underscore):

```
import re

re.findall(r"\b\w{2} \d{5}\b", "P O BOX 32370, CA 92263")
#['CA 92263']
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I add condition to grab 4 or 5 number in `\d{5}\b`? Possible?

Comment: You can specify a lower bound in `{}` like `\d{4,5}\b`. This matches 4 or 5 digits.

Answer (score 0):

> to grab text starting and space, then exact **2** **alphabets**, then one
>   space, then exact 5 digits.

Unfortunately, this pattern `\b\w{2} \d{5}\b` will also find a match in such strings as `"P O BOX 32370, 2A 92263"` giving the result which doesn't fit your requirement. `\w` - matches all alpha**numeric** characters.
To extract *State*, and *Zip code* use the following approach with [re.search()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) and [match.groupdict()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.groupdict) (gets all the named subgroups of the match) methods:

```
s = 'P O BOX 32370, CA 92263'
m = re.search(r'\b(?P<state>[a-zA-Z]{2}) (?P<zip_code>\d{5})\b', s)
result = m.groupdict() if m else ''

print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'zip_code': '92263', 'state': 'CA'}
```